# LARAVEL 9 Attempt to read property "id" on null

Tags: php, laravel

app\Http\Controllers\Frontend\IndexController
.php
 
: 23

```
<?php

use App\Models\User;

use App\Models\Category;

use App\Models\NewsPost;

use App\Models\Subcategory;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;


class IndexController extends Controller
{


    public function Index()
    {


        $skip_cat_0 = Category::skip(0)->first();


        $skip_news_0 = NewsPost::where('status', 1)->where('category_id', $skip_cat_0->id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->limit(5)->get();


        $skip_cat_2 = Category::skip(2)->first();


        $skip_news_2 = NewsPost::where('status', 1)->where('category_id', $skip_cat_2->id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->limit(6)->get();


        $skip_cat_1 = Category::skip(1)->first();


        $skip_news_1 = NewsPost::where('status', 1)->where('category_id', $skip_cat_2->id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->limit(6)->get();


        return view('frontend.index', compact('skip_cat_0', 'skip_news_0', 'skip_cat_2', 'skip_news_2', 'skip_cat_1', 'skip_news_1'));


    }


    public function NewsDetails($id, $slug)
    {
```

Comment: What line here, if any, caused that error?

Comment: $skip_cat_0, $skip_cat_1, $skip_cat_2 could be probably also null when you call first() method. You should check where these variables aren't null before accesing to id on them.

Comment: Any line where you're doing `$var = Whatever::first()`, followed by `$whatever->id` can trigger this error. `->first()` can return `null`, and `null->id` is not valid PHP. Use `->firstOrFail()`, or check them first, like `if($whatever) { // code that uses \`$whatever->id\` }`, or `$whatever?->id`, etc. This error is entirely on how you're unsafely using `->first()` and assuming that the result is not `null`.